# Generate PDF using DomPDF

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

hello i'm newbie and need your help buddy... please kindly help for a minute

So, i want to generate PDF but i dont know what should i do, please look at this

```
public function pdfview($id){
    $halaman="tindaklayanan";
    $keluhan = keluhan::findOrFail($id);

    $tindak = DB::table('tindakans')
    ->join('keluhans','keluhans.id','=','tindakans.id_keluhan')
    ->select(DB::raw('keluhans.id, perbaikan_sementara, ttd_tanggung1, ttd_tanggung2, revisi_dokumen, 
    target_verifikasi'))->get();
    //dd($tindak);

    $analisa = DB::table('analisas')
    ->join('tindakans','tindakans.id','=','analisas.id_tindakan')
    ->join('keluhans','keluhans.id','=','tindakans.id_keluhan')
    ->select(DB::raw('id_tindakan, analisa, tindakan, pic, tanggal_pelaksanaan'))->get();

    return view('Laporan.pdfview',compact('keluhan','tindak','analisa','halaman'));

    //$pdf = PDF::loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
    //return $pdf->stream();
}
```

I've an HTML view and it's finished but how to generate as PDF ? see the command line its work, but i want to load my view that compact('keluhan','tindak','analisa','halaman')

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('Laporan.pdfview',compact('keluhan','tindak','analisa','halaman'));
return $pdf->stream();
```

Its work now thank you.